# How can I search and listen to the search result in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

I really don't get the new search feature in iTunes 11. How can I for instance search for all the songs with a name containing "strauss" and listen to them?

Answer (score 1):

In the search box, write your search term, "strauss". Then use the dropdown menu to the left in the search field (the magnifying glass) to select Filter by: Song to only get matches on song name.

Make sure you have Songs selected in the main toolbar as well to get the songs in a plain list.

[image]